# Making Eclipse Recognize Imports

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, dependencies, import

I am trying to integrate Spring into my project in Eclipse. I am using Maven and have added the dependencies in my POM. While the maven build works, Eclipse does not recognize imports like the following.

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
```

How do I get Eclipse to recognize Spring imports? I am hoping there is a way to do this w/o downloading the jar files, etc.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eclipse doesn't support Maven projects natively. You must install a plugin (m2eclipse) to be able to use a Maven project inside Eclipse.

Comment: Thanks. This fixed the problem. For those who need similar help, go to http://m2eclipse.sonatype.org/installing-m2eclipse.html and add the m2eclipse plugin to Eclipse. Then right click on the project, choose Maven and Enable Dependency Management. Your project will recognize the Maven dependency imports.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to fix this is to open a command line, navigate to your project, and run `mvn clean install` and/or `mvn eclipse:eclipse` the first will parse the `pom.xml` and download all the dependencies and the second will build your eclipse meta-data files(.classpath and .project) you can even do this with the project open in eclipse and hit F5 to refresh and viola

Answer (score 0):

Check your maven path in eclipse.
Window >>> Preferences >>> Maven >>> User Settings

Check for User Settings field that contains settings.xml